# Convert string with multiple values to double precision (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

maybe someone is able to point me to the correct solution for the following problem:

I have a table with coordinates as strings like for example **'9.94 54.839'** (for some other purposes I need to keep the coordinate values in one column). For the PostGIS function ST_GeomFromText I need them as double precision values.

Example: `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(9.94 54.839)',4326)`

Another problem is that the coordinate length varies (example: **'9.873684 54.63'**)

Comment: Look at [`regexp_split_...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) functions.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Thanks for the help. With the above command I'm able to split the coordinates but the output is a string again and I'm not able to cast it to get a double precision value...

Comment: Why not? This one works fine: SELECT split_part('9.873684 54.63',' ',2)::double precision;

Comment: @TomaszMyrta This statement works for me too but if I try to use SELECT split_part(coordinate,' ',1)::double precision
FROM points; I get the ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""

Comment: It won't work for empty or broken strings. You must avoid them in where clause.

Comment: I just tested it with a new table and it works as you said... Why could it be that the string is broken? I've never heard about that before

Comment: @Jann by broken sting he means a string that contains values, different from "two double precision values separated by space". like `'asd zxc'` or just empty string `''`

Comment: Try searching for such strings with `where not your_string !~ '^[0-9.] [0-9.]$'`

Comment: Thank you all! There was one empty string (normally it shouldn't have been there) and now it works :) Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

As the function name suggests, `ST_GeomFromText` requires text—more specifically, [**well-known text**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text). Picking out double precision values is unnecessary. You just need to glue togther the pieces with a concatenation operator `||`:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || meta_string_value || ')', 4326) AS geom
FROM (
    SELECT '9.94 54.839'::text AS meta_string_value
    UNION ALL SELECT '9.873684 54.63'::text AS meta_string_value
) AS t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered your other (extremely similar) question: 
[Obtain double precision values from inconsitent strings for using ST_GeomFromText (PostGIS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220875/obtain-double-precision-values-from-inconsitent-strings-for-using-st-geomfromtex/19228410#19228410) and the answer is the same.

### Just to Recap

[According to the docs](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html), `ST_GeomFromText` requires `(text, integer)`, not `(double precision)`.

All you need to do is `CONCAT()` and it should work.

### Solution

```
ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('LINESTRING(', "YourTable"."YourString", ')'), 4326);
```

Also, if you have several values (points) that need to be connected to form a line (or polygon) take a look at `STRING_AGG(text, text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assumes a string "pos" of latitude longitude(lat lon). Split the string and cast it to float, use strip to remove any unwanted whitespaces.

```
tmp = pos.split()
lat = float(tmp[0].strip())
lon = float(tmp[1].strip())
```

You could then do something like:

```
latlonString = 'POINT(%f %f)' % (lat,lon)
```

Using the variable in a query:

```
ST_GeomFromText(latlonString,4326)
```

For example:

```
SELECT id
FROM features
WHERE pos = ST_GeomFromText(latlonString,4326)
```

For a string of multiple coordinate pairs; xyString = "x1 y1 x2 y2" NOTE! not separated by comma:

```
xyString = '3.584731 60.739211 3.590472 60.738030 3.592740 60.736220'
xy = xyString.split()
tuples  = [i+' '+j for i,j in zip(xy[::2],xy[1::2])]
multiPointString = ','.join(map(str,tuples))
polygonString = 'POLYGON((%s))' % (multiPointString)
print polygonString
```

print:

```
POLYGON((3.584731 60.739211,3.590472 60.738030,3.592740 60.736220))
```

If you have a polygon string like this: "x1 y1, x2 y2, ....", just edit the line:

```
xy = xyString.replace(",", " ").split()
```

This should be sufficient if you use psycopg2 as postgresql adapter.
Maybe it doesn't answer all your questions, but hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

With your hints I was able to get a point coordinate with the following syntax:

```
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText(((('POINT('|| split_part(t1.meta_string_value, ' ', 1)::double
    precision) || ' ') || split_part(t1.meta_string_value, ' ', 2)::double precision) ||
    ')', 4326) AS geom FROM points t1
```

Now I have a new problem. In the case above only two double precision values (LON, LAT) are needed to create a geometry out of the coordinates. What can I do if I would like to create a line or a polygon out of a list of coordinates like for example:

```
    9.873684 54.63, 9.8432 54.8792, 9.032 54.32, 8.9 54.987
```

The proble is that I don't know how much coordinates a line or polygon will have...

Any ideas about it?

Comment: Take a look at the [geometry constructors](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors), or ask a new question.

Comment: These are not double precision values... they are text.