# Obtain double precision values from inconsitent strings for using ST_GeomFromText (PostGIS)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a PostgreSQL table with a column containing strings in the following format:

```
    '3.985 58.934, 4.56 61.2323, 5.4 63.234355, 3.25982 59.309' 
    '3.985 58.934, 4.56 61.2323, 5.4 63.234355, 3.25982 59.309, 4.5632 58.32423'
    'and so on...'
```

As you can see the column contains coordinates in different lengths as **strings** in **one** line. I would like to use the PostGIS function:

```
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(3.985 58.934, 4.56 61.2323, 5.4 63.234355, 3.25982 
    59.309)', 4326)
```

The following questions now appears:

The PostGIS functions requires double precision values in the right format as shown above. How can I generate double precision values from strings when I don't know how long the strings will be and how many characters each coordinate has?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Jann

Comment: don't suppose you can fix the design to get rid of the daft multi column value?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson unfortunately not possible due to some permissions...

Comment: Well the only option I can think of then is to fix the string, which is not going to be amusing in sql.

Comment: This is the way to deal with a point coordinate:    

        `SELECT ST_GeomFromText(((('POINT('|| split_part(t1.meta_string_value, ' ', 1)::double
        precision) || ' ') || split_part(t1.meta_string_value, ' ', 2)::double precision) ||
        ')', 4326) AS geom FROM points t1`

Maybe someone has an idea how do it with a loop (or anything like this)?!

Comment: so the last point in second string has 3 coordinates?

Comment: @JakubKania sorry comma was missing...

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html), `ST_GeomFromText` requires `(text, integer)`, not `(double precision)`.

All you need to do is `CONCAT()` and it should work.

### Solution

```
ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('LINESTRING(', "YourTable"."YourString", ')'), 4326);
```

**For your testing**

```
SELECT
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(3.985 58.934, 4.56 61.2323, 5.4 63.234355, 3.25982 59.309)', 4326),
    CONCAT('LINESTRING(', "T1"."C1", ')'),
    ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('LINESTRING(', "T1"."C1", ')'), 4326)
FROM
    (
        SELECT '3.985 58.934, 4.56 61.2323, 5.4 63.234355, 3.25982 59.309, 4.5632 58.32423' AS "C1"
    ) AS "T1";
```

---

### Just for fun

I decided to convert your string into the originally requested `DOUBLE PRECISION` and then back into a string... the end result is the same as above, but it does it with a lot more work. Nevertheless, it is what you asked for.

```
SELECT
    ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('LINESTRING(', (SELECT STRING_AGG(ARRAY_TO_STRING("Line"."Points", ' '), ',') FROM REGEXP_MATCHES(ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY("T1"."C1", E', | ')::DOUBLE PRECISION[], ' '), '(\d*\.\d*) (\d*\.\d*)', 'g') AS "Line"("Points")), ')'), 4326)
FROM
    (
        SELECT '3.985 58.934, 4.56 61.2323, 5.4 63.234355, 3.25982 59.309, 4.5632 58.32423'::TEXT AS "C1"
    ) AS "T1";
```

Comment: The [`||` operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) could also be used to simplify the string concatenation.